# Encrypt in C and decrypt in Python using AES

Tags: python, c, aes, encryption

I was wondering if there is any straightforward way to encrypt text or string in C so it can easily be decrypted in python using shared key encryption (AES) ?

Comment: Which encryption algorithm are you going to use?  If you pick one that has both a C and a Python implementation, that's the straightforward way.  Which algorithm do you think you want to use?

Comment: I think I will use symmetric encryption with AES

Comment: Please **update** your question to state that you plan to use AES.  Then, please search using Google for AES implementations in Python and C.  Then, please ask any specific questions on the implementations you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) (not distributed as part of Python) implements algorithms like AES, and [Mozilla Network Security Services](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/) provides C libraries to use encryption algorithms in C. Alternatively, there is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), but its documentation is lacking.

I'd recommend a commonly used one like AES or Blowfish.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend calling GPG, the Gnu Privacy Gaurd in C via [GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/gpgme.html). You can read the data with Python using [python-gnupg](http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/). This is the most secure option since you are relying on an open source, peer reviewed, and widely used cryptography implementation (GPG). There are many, many security pitfalls when implementing cryptography. In general, application developers should not implement cryptography themselves.